ElasticNetCV in Python: Get full grid of hyperparameters with corresponding MSE?
I have fitted a ElasticNetCV in Python with three splits:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Sample data:
num_samples = 100  # Number of samples
num_features = 1000  # Number of features 
X = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_features)
Y = np.random.rand(num_samples)

#Model
l1_ratios = np.arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1)
tscv=TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=None, n_splits=3)
regr = ElasticNetCV(cv=tscv.split(X), random_state=42,l1_ratio=l1_ratios)
regr.fit(X,Y)

Now I want to get the whole grid of combinations of hyperparameters with the corresponding MSE as a Data Frame, I tried the following. However, the problem is that the resulting data frame shows the MSE for a combination of hyperparameters which are not shown as the minimum in the ElasticNetCV object which can be obtained by regr.alpha_ and regr.l1_ratio_
:
mse_path =  regr.mse_path_
alpha_path = regr.alphas_

# Reshape mse_path to have l1_ratios, n_alphas, cross_validation_step as separate columns
mse_values = mse_path.flatten()
alpha_values = alpha_path.flatten()
l1_values=np.tile(l1_ratios ,int(alpha_values.shape[0]/l1_ratios.shape[0]))
repeated_l1_ratios = np.repeat(l1_ratios, 100)

# mse has dimensions (11, 100, 3)
array_3d = mse

# Flatten the 3D array into a 2D array
# Each sub-array of shape (100, 3) becomes a row in the new 2D array
array_2d = array_3d.reshape(-1, 3)

# Create a DataFrame from the 2D array
df = pd.DataFrame(array_2d, columns=['MSE Split1', 'MSE Split2', 'MSE Split3'])

df['alpha_values'] = alpha_values
df['l1_values'] = repeated_l1_ratios

The following then results in a hyperparameter combination that is not the true one. So when combining the MSEs and the hyperparameter values, something is wrong:
# Calculate the minimum MSE for each row across the three splits
df['Min MSE'] = df[['MSE Split1', 'MSE Split2', 'MSE Split3']].min(axis=1)

# Identify the row with the overall minimum MSE
min_mse_row_index = df['Min MSE'].idxmin()

# Retrieve the row with the minimum MSE
min_mse_row = df.loc[min_mse_row_index]

print("Row with the minimum MSE across all splits:")
print(min_mse_row)


It looks to me like you've got everything right up to defining the dataframe of hyperparameters and their fold-scores.
But the "best" set of hyperparameters is the one that minimizes the MSE averaged over folds (not minimized over folds).

so to find the minimal MSE chosen by ElasticNetCV, I need to first average the MSEs over all folds? Any hint how I could do that in the given code efficiently?

Just replace min by mean in your definition of df['Min MSE'] = df[['MSE Split1', 'MSE Split2', 'MSE Split3']].min(axis=1)

Thanks. That works. However, also had to edit the flatten of the alpha values slightly to get to the correct order in df, will add the code that seems to be working to the original post.

@Ben Reiniger 's post solved the issue. However, one more slight change to the code in the original code had to be made: alpha_path.flatten("C") instead of alpha_path.flatten() to get the alphas in the correct order.
So the following code should do it:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Sample data:
num_samples = 100  # Number of samples
num_features = 1000  # Number of features 
X = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_features)
Y = np.random.rand(num_samples)

#Model
l1_ratios = np.arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1)
tscv=TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=None, n_splits=3)
regr = ElasticNetCV(cv=tscv.split(X), random_state=42,l1_ratio=l1_ratios)
regr.fit(X,Y)

se = regr.mse_path_
regr.alphas_
regr.alpha_
regr.l1_ratio
regr.l1_ratio_

mse_path =  regr.mse_path_
alpha_path = regr.alphas_

# Reshape mse_path to have l1_ratios, n_alphas, cross_validation_step as separate columns
mse_values = mse_path.flatten()
alpha_values = alpha_path.flatten("C")
l1_values=np.tile(l1_ratios ,int(alpha_values.shape[0]/l1_ratios.shape[0]))
repeated_l1_ratios = np.repeat(l1_ratios, 100)

# mse has dimensions (11, 100, 3)
array_3d = mse

# Flatten the 3D array into a 2D array
# Each sub-array of shape (100, 3) becomes a row in the new 2D array
array_2d = array_3d.reshape(-1, 3)

# Create a DataFrame from the 2D array
df = pd.DataFrame(array_2d, columns=['MSE Split1', 'MSE Split2', 'MSE Split3'])

df['alpha_values'] = alpha_values
df['l1_values'] = repeated_l1_ratios


# Calculate the minimum MSE for each row across the three splits
df['Min MSE'] = df[['MSE Split1', 'MSE Split2', 'MSE Split3']].mean(axis=1)

# Identify the row with the overall minimum MSE
min_mse_row_index = df['Min MSE'].idxmin()

# Retrieve the row with the minimum MSE
min_mse_row = df.loc[min_mse_row_index]

print("Row with the minimum MSE across all splits:")
print(min_mse_row)

